# Solving differential equations numerically with a singularity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve a second order differential numerically which is of the following form

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = y$$ 
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{A(y,x)}{B(y,x)}$$
with proper initial conditions. However, for certain initial conditions,
 $A(y(t_c), x(t_c))=B(y(t_c),x(t_c))=0$.
As a result, the numerical integrator is unable to proceed beyond $t=t_c$ with the integration. I would like to stress that the above value of $t_c$ is not available to me before the integration, i.e., I can't predict the singularity point due to complicated nature of $A, B$. I have no idea on how to proceed with these type of problem. I am a student of Physics and my knowledge of differential equation is only up to the applied level. So, please help and also I would be much obliged if someone refer me to appropriate literature where I can learn more about the issue.

Comment: If $B=0$ at any time, then you shouldn't expect a solution to persist past that time.

Comment: @David, If A=0, simultaneously, will that change anything?

Comment: 0/0 is still undefined, so no.